# Checking if two Models belongs to a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: django, many-to-many

I had a many-to-many relationship between two Django Models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
    bees = models.ManyToManyField('Bee')
class Bee(models.Model):
    ...
```

in my template, I want to have a different output depending on whether the user has certain Bees. What I'm doing right now is to create a custom filter that does something resembling this:

```
@register.filter
def my_filter(user, bee):
    userprofile = user.get_profile()
    return bee in userprofile.bees.all()
```

and in the template, I can use it as such:

```
{% for bee in bees %}
    {% if user|my_filter:bee %}
        I am in {{ bee }}
    {% else %}
        I am not in {{ bee }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

but this seems hackish since 1) I called .all() -- loading the all Bees including the bees that I'm not interested in -- without using the results, 2) I don't think I should need to create a custom filter as this should be quite common

What is the proper way to check whether a Model belongs to a many-to-many relationship with another Model?

Comment: What is "bee" supposed to be in your filter? I guess, what is "bees" in relation to "bee"?

Comment: @Bryce Siedschlaw: bees is a plural of bee (I generally uses plural names for containers (e.g. list, dicts) or database tables, and singular names for non-containers or database rows. Also, I just added a few corrections to make the question less confusing (I apologize for writing at 4am in the morning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the list of the user's bee ids in your view. Something like this:

```
def view(request):
    user_bee_ids = request.user.bees.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

And then in your template you can do this:

```
{% if bee.pk in user_bee_ids %}
    I am in {{ bee }}
{% else %}
    I am not in {{ bee }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the check in your template you could take a look at the [`in operator`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator).

```
{% if special_bee in profile_instance.bees.all %}
    This profile is related to this special bee.
{% endif %}
```